# willSave() not called when RestKit updates my data

Tags: swift, core-data, restkit

I have a willSave method in my NSManagedObject. It is being called when a new record needs to be added, but when RestKit using its:

```
        defaultMapping.identificationAttributes = ["upcCode"]
```

Doesn't call willSave()

```
override public  func willSave() {
        if(productName != nil && productName != ""){
            let sk = String(productName!.characters.first!).capitalizedString
            if((sectionKey == nil || sectionKey == "") || (sectionKey != sk)){
                sectionKey = sk
            }
        }else{
            sectionKey = "X"
        }
```

WHY?

Comment: would it not be better to set a default value for `sectionKey` and override the setter for `productName` to add this logic...

Comment: I had it changed at the server level as this also gave us better control of sorting. But yes, probably overriding the setter would get around this. I just don't understand why willSave() doesn't get called on update.